# find function isn't working properly in angular and firebase

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firebase, web

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc04H.png)

when im enter the find id and data set isn't set on this fields and  this error occured in my console .

the below code shows findexpense code snippets

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ExpensesService} from "../../Expenses.service";
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-find-expenses-data',
  templateUrl: './find-expenses-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./find-expenses-data.component.scss']
})
export class FindExpensesDataComponent {
  constructor(private service:ExpensesService) {
  }

  expenseDataform=new FormGroup({
    title:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    des :new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    cost :new FormControl(0,Validators.required)
  });
  findData(){

    this.service.finddatabyid(this.expenseDataform.get('id')?.value!)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.expenseDataform.patchValue({
          title:response.title,
          des:response.des,
          cost:response.cost,
        });
        },error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
}
```

and this is the servise.ts file

```
  finddatabyid(id:string):Observable<any>{
  return this.store.doc(`expense/${id}`).valueChanges({idField:'id'});
  }
```

and finally this is my html file

```
<form [formGroup]="expenseDataform">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="column">

      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="id"id="id">ID</label>
          <input (keyup.enter)="findData()"  type="text"class="form-control"formControlName="id">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title"id="title">Title</label>
          <input type="text"class="form-control"formControlName="title">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="des"id="des">Description</label>
          <input type="text"class="form-control"formControlName="des">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="cost"id="cost">Cost</label>
          <input type="number"class="form-control"formControlName="cost">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

my saving function is working properly but this finding function does not working.i am fresher for this field could anyone help me please .

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `expenseDataform` is missing the form control for id. Modifying it as below should solve the error

```
expenseDataform=new FormGroup({
    id: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    title: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    des: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    cost: new FormControl(0,Validators.required)
  });
```